# webpack build css rules have different order then in development

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js

I am not sure if this is a webpack issue, vue-loader for webpack issue or just something that I am doing wrong.

When I am running `npm run build` to build a distribution for my Vue.js application the CSS rules applied in the dist app are in different order then in my development environment thus my CSS overrides are different and app doesn't render right...

Here is demonstration for one element:

`npm run dev` - proper render
[image]

`npm run build` - improper render
[image]

UPDATE: added webpack config files

`webpack.base.conf.js`

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/static'),
    publicPath: '/static/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src')
    }
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
  },
  module: {
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jp?g|gif|svg|woff2?|eot|ttf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loaders: [
          'url?limit=20000&name=[name].[ext]?[hash:7]',
          'image-webpack?{progressive:true, optimizationLevel: 7, interlaced: false, pngquant:{quality: "65-90", speed: 4}}'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      }
    ]
  },
  eslint: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      sass: 'style!css!sass?indentedSyntax'
    }
  },
  stylus: {
    use: [require('nib')()],
    import: ['~nib/lib/nib/index.styl']
  }
}
```

`webpack.dev.conf.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

// eval-source-map is faster for development
config.devtool = '#eval-source-map'

// add hot-reload related code to entry chunks
var polyfill = 'eventsource-polyfill'
var devClient = './build/dev-client'
Object.keys(config.entry).forEach(function (name, i) {
  var extras = i === 0 ? [polyfill, devClient] : [devClient]
  config.entry[name] = extras.concat(config.entry[name])
})

// necessary for the html plugin to work properly
// when serving the html from in-memory
config.output.publicPath = '/'

config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
  // https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware#installation--usage
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: 'src/index.html',
    inject: true
  })
])

module.exports = config
```

`webpack.prod.conf.js`

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

// naming output files with hashes for better caching.
// dist/index.html will be auto-generated with correct URLs.
config.output.filename = '[name].[chunkhash].js'
config.output.chunkFilename = '[id].[chunkhash].js'

// whether to generate source map for production files.
// disabling this can speed up the build.
var SOURCE_MAP = true

config.devtool = SOURCE_MAP ? 'source-map' : false

// generate loader string to be used with extract text plugin
function generateExtractLoaders (loaders) {
  return loaders.map(function (loader) {
    return loader + '-loader' + (SOURCE_MAP ? '?sourceMap' : '')
  }).join('!')
}

// http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/configurations/extract-css.html
var cssExtractLoaders = {
  css: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('vue-style-loader', generateExtractLoaders(['css'])),
  less: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('vue-style-loader', generateExtractLoaders(['css', 'less'])),
  sass: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('vue-style-loader', generateExtractLoaders(['css', 'sass'])),
  stylus: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('vue-style-loader', generateExtractLoaders(['css', 'stylus']))
}

config.vue = config.vue || {}
config.vue.loaders = config.vue.loaders || {}
Object.keys(cssExtractLoaders).forEach(function (key) {
  config.vue.loaders[key] = cssExtractLoaders[key]
})

config.plugins = (config.plugins || []).concat([
  // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/workflow/production.html
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: '"production"'
    }
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
    compress: {
      warnings: false
    }
  }),
  new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
  // extract css into its own file
  new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[contenthash].css'),
  // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
  // you can customize output by editing /src/index.html
  // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: '../index.html',
    template: 'src/index.html',
    inject: true,
    minify: {
      removeComments: true,
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      removeAttributeQuotes: true
      // more options:
      // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
    }
  })
])

module.exports = config
```

Comment: Without any configs I can only suggest that you need [OccurenceOrderPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#occurrenceorderplugin)

Comment: @BobSponge have added my webpack config files if it helps...

Comment: You need to use [insertAt](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader#insertat) parameter with value `top` for scss `style-loader`

Comment: @BobSponge but I do not use `require()` to include these styles. There css rules are defined as a part of *.vue files in `<style></style>` tags? And when running dev version `npm run dev` they are included in the right order...?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. How scss, vue and less (?) files are including in bundle? Order of files broken due `ExtractTextPlugin` but I cant understand why scss files are not in the bundle.

Comment: @BobSponge I only use scss and vue files into... Not sure what you mean "...why scss files are not in the bundle"? They are... the problem is the styles I define in my vue component files are included before scss files even though I include my main scss file before... It works ok in dev environment.

Comment: this work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628609/how-do-i-correct-the-css-compile-order-with-webpack-in-vuejs

Answer (score 0):

What helped me, was tapping into the html plugin config, by adding this to `vue.config.js`

```
 chainWebpack: config => {
            config
                .plugin('html')
                .tap(args => {
                    args[0].chunksSortMode = function (chunk1, chunk2) {
                        const order = ['first', 'second', 'third']
                        const order1 = order.indexOf(chunk1.names[0])
                        const order2 = order.indexOf(chunk2.names[0])
                        return order1 - order2
                    }
                    return args
                })
    },
```