# How do I correct the css compile order with webpack in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2

I have a issue about css compile order in Webpack 2 with vue-cli project.

In main.js, I imported a css library file named `skeleton.css` . This include `<a>` color style.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import 'skeleton-css/css/skeleton.css'
```

In App.vue, I set `<a>` color style as below

```
<style lang="scss">
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #2c3e50;
    }
</style>
```

When I compiled the code and open the chrome inspector. I found the wrong order insert style.

```
<style type="text/css">....</style> // App.vue inline style
<style type="text/css">....</style> // skeleton.css style
```

And my webpack 2 config with vue-cli

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{
        loader: "style-loader"
    }, {
        loader: "css-loader"
    }, {
        loader: "sass-loader"
    }]
}
```

How should I do to adjust correct import style order?

Answer (score 10):

You need reorder the `imports` in your `main.js`, since it is the only thing that affects the order of `<style>` tags in the resulting DOM:

```
import 'skeleton-css/css/skeleton.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
```

Now `skeleton.css` comes first, and everything else would come after it.

Comment: Is that a standard way to structure ?

Comment: @tommychoo there is no "standard way to structure". It just solves (hopefully) the particular problem you explained.

Comment: Thanks, but it look like some strange.

Comment: @tommychoo how so? If you want a skeleton to come first - you put it first. I honestly cannot understand why it surprises you :-)

Comment: You have to be careful to not use any autoformatters which reorder imports. Or accidentally reorder them by yourself.