# CSS file has no effect on Vue prod build

Tags: css, vue.js, amazon-s3, gitlab-ci

I have a Vue project with a single file component using a chart module. To override some styles in the chart module's CSS I have a custom CSS file in the assets folder containing the lines which override some styles (dark background instead of white, etc.)  It is working nicely with npm run dev and I can see the changes at localhost no problem.

I have an S3 bucket and I use Gitlab CI to update my site with tagged builds. However, after the update, the mentioned styles seems to be not affected. I checked the S3 bucket and the generated CSS do contains the new lines but I can't see them in effect. Any tip would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not some kind of caching problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I checked that with Ctrl+F5.

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, [Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), configuration or everything can help?

Comment: @JustGreg If you use Chrome you can open developer tools (F12) and then right click on the page reload button next to the URL text input and click 'Empty Cache & Hard Reload'.

Comment: @JKL Done that, same issue.

Comment: @ManUtopiK I'm not sure I can provide a minimal example as the project is quite complex and my primary problem is that it is working on localhost flawlessly...the issue shows up in my aws s3 bucket only after updating with Gitlab CI.

Comment: What build steps are you using in your Gitlab CI pipeline and do you use a module bundler to build your app?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. It seems I've run into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021225/webpack-build-css-rules-have-different-order-then-in-development). I managed to reproduce it by building a production build using *npm run build*. To serve the *dist* package I installed *serve* and checked on localhost:5000:

```
sudo npm install -g serve
serve -s dist
```

This way I could experiment with different CSS styles without using Gitlab CI. The problem was with the CSS order, I had to import my custom CSS file in the component not in main.js and had to use !important in styles.